# Delphi VCL Custom TCombobox Dropdown Width

Tags: windows, delphi, combobox, vcl

I have a simple descendant of Delphi's VCL TCombobox for a very special customer showcase. It has only 2 features (separator lines, multi-line items) that I did not find on a ready-to-use component. Works fine, but I'm unable to control the size of the dropdown area / flyout menu below. I did what I found googling that:

```
procedure TMyownCombobox.DropDown;
begin
inherited;
var iDropdownHeight:=360;
// does NOT work, as it affects the width, not the height of the flyout
// according to WinAPI documentation, there is no equivalent of CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH for the height ("CB_SETDROPPEDHEIGHT")
SendMessage(Self.Handle, CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH,Width,MakeLParam(iDropdownHeight,0));
end;
```

Unfortunately, size is always about 100px, no matter how many items there are. Settingt th DropdownCount property has no affect. Rendering the items works great, but users have to scroll a lot. When rendering my items, there is a MeasureItem() procedure that I implemented myself, but I could'nt find anything like that for the flyout menu.

Comment: Did you actually read the documentation of CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH? In the first parameter you've specified "Width" which is the width of the combobox itself and I presume it is 100 pixels. The second one (LPARAM) is not used by CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH, so no need to specify it at all.
To set the drop down height, use Combobox.DropDownCount

Comment: Yes, I've read the documentation. But there is no "See also" link to a "CB_SETDROPPEDHEIGHT" message. Setting the DropDownCount property was the 1st thing I did, but it has no effect. Anyway, I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: There is no `CB_SETDROPPEDHEIGHT`

Comment: At least link to your "_found googling_" source - it's the internet and it works through links. [Documentation of `CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-setdroppedwidth); for the list height your component already has the [`.DropDownCount` property](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomCombo.DropDownCount).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-setdroppedwidth) message is used to set the width of the drop down list:

> An application sends the `CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH` message to set the minimum allowable width, in pixels, of the list box of a combo box with the `CBS_DROPDOWN` or `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST` style.

Hence, it will not affect the height.

To set the height, you use the [`CB_SETMINVISIBLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-setminvisible) message:

> Sets the minimum number of visible items in the drop-down list of a combo box.

For example,

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SendMessage(ComboBox1.Handle, CB_SETDROPPEDWIDTH, 200, 0);
  SendMessage(ComboBox1.Handle, CB_SETMINVISIBLE, 50, 0);
end;
```

Please note that the width unit is pixels, while the height unit is items.

[image: Screenshot of large combo box drop down list.]

However, the VCL already provides you with an interface to these messages in its `DropDownWidth` and `DropDownCount` properties:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComboBox1.DropDownWidth := 200;
  ComboBox1.DropDownCount := 50;
end;
```

So you don't need to send any messages explicitly yourself.

If this doesn't work for you in your particular application, then you have some strange things going on in this app, which we cannot see.

One very common cause of malfunctioning VCL GUIs is that the programmer uses VCL styles (or themes) to give the app a non-standard appearance.